# Get input stream as source for Hadoop map method

Tags: hadoop, inputstream

I am working with set of files from directory, which is output of another task. I need to process content of entire file at once (calculate MD5 checksums and do some transformations). I'm not sure how signature of my Mapper should look like, if I will make is as

```
class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, NullWritable, NullWritable> { ... }
```

then I will get entire content of an input file in in **map** method. And this will be stored in memory, but files could be quite big.

Is there any way to not read the complete "record" into memory for processing by Hadoop map task, but get a "stream" for the record?

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need to worry about it. Hadoop is optimized to leverage all the resources of your cluster to do the jobs. The whole point of it is to abstract away the low level details of all that and let you focus on your use case.

I assure you Hadoop can handle your files. If they are really big and/or your cluster has less powerful or unreliable machines, then the jobs might take longer. But they won't fail (absent any other errors).

So I think your approach is fine. The only suggestion I would make is to consider avoiding canonical MapReduce because it isn't a high *enough* level of abstraction. Consider [Cascading](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/userguide/htmlsingle/) or [JCascalog](https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog/wiki/JCascalog) instead.